# CRM 2013 How to debug retrieve plugin?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to debug a retrieve plugin, but unable to use plugin registration tool, is there any other way to debug this type of plugin?

Comment: I suggest the tried and true approach of adding logging statements to your plugin.

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't use Plugin Registration Tool. Could you please provide information how you use it?

Comment: The Plugin Registration Tool, and the Plugin Profiler is the correct answer.
Why can't you use it?  If you can connect to CRM, then the tool will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ITracingService** as shown below. Using tracing service you can trace the cause of the issue.

```
public class MyPlugin : IPlugin
{
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        IPluginExecutionContext context =
            (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
        ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

        IOrganizationServiceFactory factory;
        IOrganizationService service;

        try
        {
            tracingService.Trace("initialize context, factory and service...");
            factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));

            tracingService.Trace("CreateOrganizationService()");
            service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Retrieve and RetrieveMultiple will usually not provide the Trace log, even if they throw an error.